# Editor stripping out data attribute when saving

Tags: tinymce, html

I am on the Text version of the page editor on the backend and whenever I try to use something like `<div data-100="1500"></div>` and click the update button the data section is stripped out an it returns `<div></div>`.

I searched around for a bit and all I could find was reference to the [Raw HTML plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) but honestly I dont want to be committed to a plugin.  Is there anyway to remove this functionality to allow me to use some data attributes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The "Text" editor is not an HTML editor. If you want to be able to edit raw HTML you will need to use some other editor, but that will probably limit your ability to use the visual editor for the content edited with it. The plugin you mentioned seems like good compromise.
The other alternative is to write your own shortcodes for whatever you need to be done.

Comment: +1. I agree. If you need to add html stuff you can use the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).